# C# XMLReader not parsing correctly

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xmlreader

I don't want to use XMLDocument because i've written the XML Writing code using XMLWriter. So there should be no reason why to switch.

```
<Player>
  <Friends />
  <Ignores>
    <Ignore>117779</Ignore>
    <Ignore>44237636758361374</Ignore>
    <Ignore>564534831</Ignore>
  </Ignores>
  <InventoryItems>
    <Item>
      <Slot>0</Slot>
      <Id>995</Id>
      <Amount>39493</Amount>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Slot>27</Slot>
      <Id>1049</Id>
      <Amount>12</Amount>
    </Item>
  </InventoryItems>
  <BankItems />
</Player>
```

I'm trying to parse that out there. Here is what I got so far. Seems to break everywhere I had it working a bit with `<Ignore>'s` but thats when I used `ReadToFollowing` instead of `ReadToNextSibling`, it would work until ReadToFollowing hit a empty line.. and it would just hit up to EOF.

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(misc.getServerPath() + "\\accounts\\" + username + ".xml");
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Friends") {
        if (!reader.IsEmptyElement) //got any friends
        {
            while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Friend"))
                //do_stuff_with_that_data(reader.ReadElementContentAsLong());
        }
    } else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Ignores") {
        if (!reader.IsEmptyElement) //got any ignores
        {
            reader.ReadToFollowing("Ignore");
            while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("Ignore"))
            {
                //do_stuff_with_that_data(reader.ReadElementContentAsLong());
            }
        }
    } else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "InventoryItems") {
        if (!reader.IsEmptyElement) //got items
        {
            int slot, id, amount;
            while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("Item"))
            {
                reader.ReadToFollowing("Slot");
                slot = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                reader.ReadToFollowing("Id");
                id = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                reader.ReadToFollowing("Amount");
                amount = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                //do_stuff_with_that_data(slot, id, amount);
            }
        }
    } else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "BankItems") {
        if (!reader.IsEmptyElement) //got bank items
        {
            int slot, id, amount;
            while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("Item"))
            {
                reader.ReadToFollowing("Slot");
                slot = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                reader.ReadToFollowing("Id");
                id = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                reader.ReadToFollowing("Amount");
                amount = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                //do_stuff_with_that_data(slot, id, amount);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So there should be no reason why to switch.

There's a very good reason to switch to a DOM-style representation unless your documents are too large to reasonably fit in memory: *it's much easier to work with that representation*.

`XmlReader` is frankly a pain to use. It's not clear exactly what's wrong (you say it "seems to break everywhere" but not exactly what's happening) but I would *strongly* advise you to move to a simpler model. Your code will be considerably simpler afterwards. If you can *possibly* use LINQ to XML instead of the pre-3.5 API, that will make your life even better.

If you *absolutely insist* on using `XmlReader`, I suggest you update your post with a simpler piece of XML and code which demonstrates the problem. I'd also suggest that you restructure your code to test for the node type being an element *once*, and then refactor the "handling an element" part into a separate method... where you may well want to switch on the element name and handle each kind of element in a separate method. Smaller methods are generally easier to understand, test and debug.

Comment: XmlReader is fantastic if you require maximum performance or have documents too large to fit into RAM.  For everything else I’d recommend using LINQ to XML – I’ve been able to replace >200 line XmlReader parsers with more concise <50 line LINQ to XML queries.  It’s very much worth it!